# What does it mean to "apply for permission to stay in UK"?

Tags: united-kingdom, overstay

Currently I am in the in the UK. I have got a 2nd letter from the home office after explaining why I worked more than 20 hours because I was on a student visa and my wife who was supposed to be my dependent was pregnant and couldn’t give support. I had to work extra because I did time we came into the Uk I paid my school fee in full and also paid 6 month rent twice that 12 months rent I was left with nothing with my wife who was pregnant and later gave birth to our first child.

So after explaining to them in the first letter I received from the home office that said I should stop work and that I should leave the UK or I should let them know why they should allow me to stay in they UK.

Since august I did so, but I received a 2nd letter from the Home Office. The letter said I should make a new application or leave the UK. They gave 3 options of next steps that I must do one of immediately:

1. applying for permission to stay in the Uk
2. was seek help and advise to return home
3. was leave the Uk

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question, but 'apply permission to stay' simply means apply for a visa. However, it's unlikely in the situation you are in that there is any visa you are eligible to apply for.

Comment: While @MJeffryes is probably right about your chances, your best source of information in this situation is going to be an immigration lawyer.  There are charlatans in the business, so proceed with caution.

Answer (score 3):

*”Apply for permission to stay”* means *apply for a new visa from within the UK*.

Breaching the work restrictions of a student visa is a very serious matter. Your immigration application can be refused, or you can be [removed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/difference-between-deportation-and-removal) from the UK, if you work too many hours or if you do work which you are not allowed to do. You might also be barred from returning to the UK for a certain period.

In the situation you describe, it seems very unlikely that there is any visa you are eligible for. If you’ve not done so already you should get [specialist immigration advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/immigration/get-help/get-immigration-advice/)